# Example of Normed Spaces $X$ and $Y$ and a linear operator $T$, so that $\ker (T)$ is not closed.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

So first, I thought about the zero transformation, however I saw it would not work. After that, I thought about the differentiation transformation, being $X$ and $Y$ the set of all infinitely differentiable functions, however $\ker(T)$ would be closed, since it would be the set of all constant functions, wouldn't it?

Can anyone help or just give a hint of something I am not thinking about? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can never find a continuous linear operator $T$ with $\operatorname{ker} T$ not closed as $\operatorname{ker} T = T^{-1}(\{0\})$ is a preimage of a closed set.

Comment: @Alex You can accept an answer or seek clarification by editing your question or using the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Let $V$ be a normed space. Then if $\tau: V \to \mathbb{C}$ is a linear map, the following two statements are equivalent:

1. $\tau$ is continuous.
2. $\ker(\tau)$ is closed in $V$.

This fact can be found in virtually every basic functional analysis book.

---

Hence, your example will be found once we construct a linear map $\tau: V \to \Bbb{C}$ such that $\tau$ is not continuous! To do this, we proceed as follows: let $V$ be your favorite  infinite-dimensional normed vector space with Hamel basis $\{e_n:n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. By rescaling the basis, we may assume that $\|e_n\| = 1$ for all $n \in \Bbb{N}$. Define a linear map $\tau:  V \to \mathbb{C}$ by
$\tau (e_n) = n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then
$$\|\tau\|= \sup_{\|v \| \leq 1} |\tau(v)| \geq n$$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, so that $\|\tau\| = \infty.$ Hence, $\tau$ is not continuous and $\ker(\tau)$ is not closed in $V$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

For a continuous operator $T$ this can never work,
because then the kernel is always closed.

Choose a linear operator $T$ which is not continuous
and which has a non-trivial kernel!
Then the chances are good that the kernel is not closed.

Comment: In case that $Y = \mathbb K$ is your base field, closedness of the kernel is equivalent to continuity of the functional.